# If the sum of the distances is the distance from start to finish, show that the points are collinear

Tags: real-analysis

> For a natural number $n$, let $x_0,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^k$. Suppose $$d(x_0,x_n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}d(x_i,x_{i+1}).$$ Prove that there exist real numbers $0\leq t_1\leq \cdots\leq t_n\leq 1$, such that $x_i=(1-t_i)x_0+t_ix_n$ for each $0<i<n$.

Answer (score 1):

Equality holds in the triangle inequality $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ for $x,y, z \in \mathbb R^n$ when the points are collinear with $y$ between $x$ and $z$. (hint: you can use Cauchy-Schwarz to prove the triangle inequality, including the equality case).

This gives you the case when $n = 2$. Then use induction on $n$ in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This does not hold with $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|_\infty$. Take the points $x_1 = (0,0), x_2 = (1,1), x_3 = (2,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $d(x_1,x_3) = d(x_1,x_2)+d(x_2,x_3)$, but the points are clearly not collinear.

Comment: here the metric is not euclidean metric,so u have to realise that the idea of "collinear" is different from euclidean metric